# Python Jupyter - Change default font

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I want to change the default font (to Gill sans) that displays in Jupyter, but am having problems knowing where I go to edit it.

I have looked in the .ipython folder and I have no Static folder, and I have looked in the .jupyter folder and it is empty.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify the styles of Jupyter notebook by adding values to the file in;

`.jupyter\custom\custom.css`

If the `custom` dir isn't in `.jupyter` just make it and add `custom.css` in it.

In your new blank `custom.css` file you can add something like this to change the font for the code mirror;

```
.CodeMirror pre, .CodeMirror-dialog, .CodeMirror-dialog .CodeMirror-search-field, .terminal-app .terminal {
    font-family: YOUR-FAV-FONT;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Here is a example of a [pimped out custom.css](https://github.com/draperjames/one-dark-notebook/blob/master/custom.css). It's from my [one-dark-notebook repo](https://github.com/draperjames/one-dark-notebook) on github. feel free to clone/fork it and do whatever.

Comment: Hey, thank you, but aside from a 'migrated' file, my .jupyter folder is empty?

Comment: Make sure to clear you browser's cache and and reload when changing the styles.

Comment: Thank you James. I will have a play around and do some research on what part I need to change, but it seems to be doing something, so thank you VERY much :)

Comment: Okay also what do you mean by the default font? Cus I just added the CodeMirror one in my answer.

Comment: Also you should fork that repo I just linked to and accept this dope answer :)

Comment: Ye, sorry, I am using codemirror :)... I will check out that repo! Thank you! I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: Oh, one last question. When you say 'make sure to clear you browser's cache'... do you mean everything? like passwords, browsing history etc?

Comment: Naw just the cache. and don't forget to reload.

Comment: Press F12 in the Firefox and point cursor on divs which are in the notebook to see what CSS classes should be overriden.

Comment: @JamesDraper: do you know what the default font is for Jupyter? I'm trying to match it in BBEdit and I can't find it.

Comment: @NLR I don't know off the top of my head but I think it's consolas.

Comment: Now this wouldn't work directly if we didn't add `! important` in the end.

Answer (score 5):

You can change font size, background themes,   cell widths etc.. from the command line. Check out the following GitHub page.
https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes

Answer (score 3):

You can set defalut  font at:  /.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py or from the command line. Check out this document (page 23) for a command line example
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/qtconsole/latest/qtconsole.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it now :)