# How do I increase the space on the input section on Jupyter Notebook? I cannot see anything on the very right of the input box

Tags: pandas, jupyter

title.

As seen below, I cannot see the very end of the line of code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcJ1O.png)

Comment: Which version of jupyter are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

To change width of cells in current notebook just enter

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

As suggested [by jjinking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270)

If this is still not sufficient you could decrease font size by going to

```
 .jupyter\custom\custom.css
```

and changing font size as suggested  [by James Draper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45544870)